# BeautifulSoup Find Randomly Returning None

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

We are trying to scrape products from Urban Outfitters and are having some weird issues with the BeautifulSoup find method. We call soup.find('span', {"class" : "mainPrice ng-scope ng-binding"}) on a product url to get the price. As we go through the product urls (through web crawling), the soup.find call will return none at random times.

For instance, on one running of the program, it returns none on the second link. When running the program immediately after without changing anything, it got past the second link and failed on the 8th link. [Here is a link to our output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTUee.jpg)

Below is our code:

```
    def findPrice(soup):
      price = soup.find('span', {"class" : "mainPrice ng-scope ng-binding"})
      print price
      if price is not None:
        return price.text.strip()

    def postProduct(url):
      driver.get(url)
      html = driver.page_source
      soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
      product = {'brand': findBrand(soup), 'name': findProductName(soup), 'price': findPrice(soup), 'image': findImageLink(soup), 'description': findDescription(soup), 'url': url}
      # products.insert(product)
```

Note that irrelevant functions have been left out. Below is the loop in which we call the postProduct function:

[Link to the loop containing postProduct function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMi6F.png)

Any help that can be provided with this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you're scraping web content and get different results from one run of your web scraper to the next, even when you haven't made any changes in your program, the most likely explanation is that the retrieved web content is changing from one run to the next.

Try catching the `findPrice` failure and dumping the page source the next time it happens, and see why your `soup.find` call can't find what it's looking for.